# Java: How does references to relocatable objects work?

Tags: java

By relocatable objects, I mean objects that can relocate itself in memory when there is not enough consecutive space. (for example ArrayList)

```
 List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
 List<String> list2 = list1;
```

If I keep adding things to list1, it will eventually relocate because there is not enough continuous address space. Then will list2 and list still point to the same address or not? If so, how is it done underneath?

Comment: So which are you asking? How the Java language works or how the JVM manages memory?

Comment: list1  and list2 point in the same memory location

Comment: Actually, `ArrayList` is a fixed-size class.  The only variable-sized objects in the entire JVM are arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No object can relocate itself. What happens here is that `list1` and `list2` point to the same object and this object (i.e. the `ArrayList`) contains another reference to the actual storrage (i.e. the array that is used to store the data). If the list grows too big, the pointer to the storrage array changes, not the location of the `ArrayList` object itself.